# Multi-level has_many, through with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm trying to make a three-tiered relationship in Rails that looks something like this.

```
+---------+      +---------+
| Brand 1 |      | Brand 2 |
++------+-+      +---+---+-+
 |      `------------|---|-------------.
 |                   |   `-----------. |
+v-----------+    +--v---------+    +v-v---------+
| Category 1 |    | Category 2 |    | Category 3 |
++------+----+    +--+-+-------+    +----------+-+
 |      |            | |                       |
 |      `----------. | `-------------.         `---------.
+v-----------+    +v-v---------+    +v-----------+    +--v---------+
| Template 1 |    | Template 2 |    | Template 3 |    | Template 4 |
+------------+    +------------+    +------------+    +------------+
```

Notice that `Template 2` is a member of both `Category 1` and `Category 2`, and that each of *those* categories are in different brands. Likewise, notice that `Category 3` is shared between two brands.

The relationships right now are defined as follows.

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
  has_many :templates, through: :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
  has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
end

class Template < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :brands, through: :categories
end
```

I cannot update the `Brand-Template` relationship, so no template is "filtered" by brand because the categories are shared. I receive this error presently.

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly at /templates/7
>   Cannot modify association 'Template#brands' because it goes through more than one other association.

How can I change the `Brand-Template` relationship to solve this problem?

Comment: Category belong_to :brand does not fall in place with your design mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `Brand-Template` to `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Now I can just write a scope on `Template` like so:

```
scope :by_brand, ->(id) { joins(:brands).where(brands: { id: id }) }
```

It makes my query a bit cumbersome but it works. It does make me wonder if there's a more efficient query though.